# Se variável for em branco substituir

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma variável $nome

```
$nome = str_replace("-"," ",strtolower($arrayReturn['nome']));
```

E chamo ela da seguinte forma:

```
<p>Nome: (<?php echo $nome; ?>) </p>
```

Acontece que as vezes essa variável não retorna valor, ficando apenas ().

Eu gostaria de incluir o () direto em $nome e se não retornar valor o não aparecer nada.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use um ternário verificando se há caractere em `$arrayReturn['nome']`. Se houver, você concatena a tag com o nome, se não, retorna nada `''`:

```
<?php
$nome = $arrayReturn['nome'] ? "<p>Nome:  (".str_replace("-"," ",strtolower($arrayReturn['nome'])).")</p>" : '';
?>
<?php echo $nome; ?>
```

Comment: Perfeito dvd! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,

Antes de chamar o paragrafo adicione um if

```
<?php
$nome = str_replace("-"," ",strtolower($arrayReturn['nome']));

 if ($nome == null){
 $nome = "()";
}
?>

<p>Nome: <?php echo $nome; ?> </p>
```